# How to map complex type to OData v4 entity model?

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, odata

I have a complex type in my application which is stored in a database. When querying an object of that type with an OData v4 controller, the data from the object's member that is a class itself doesn't get mapped / exported as Json at all. How do I properly specify such an entity type to OData v4? Right now I think I have to modify GetEdmModel() properly, but I don't know how.

**Type of member of complex type**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Net;

[Owned]
public class FileInfo
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Filename { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [StringLength(3)]
    public string Filetype { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Contenttype { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public long Filesize { get; set; } = -1;
}
```

**Complex Type**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public partial class DocumentProperties
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;

    [StringLength(2000)]
    public string Description { get; set; } = String.Empty;

    public DateTime? IssuingDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;

    public FileInfo FileInfo { get; set; } = new();
}
```

**GetEdmModel**

```
static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<DocumentProperties>("Documents");
    builder.EntitySet<DS2.Shared.Models.FileInfo>("FileInfo");
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

**Json from OData controller**

```
{@odata.context: "https://localhost:7046/DS2/$metadata#Documents/$entity",…}
    @odata.context: "https://localhost:7046/DS2/$metadata#Documents/$entity"
    ID: "cc8ff2ce-8be9-4de3-a5ba-780c6e81a83d"
    Description: "Test"
    IssuingDate: "2022-05-31T00:00:00+02:00"
```

The data from the FileInfo member is completely missing.

**Json from regular Api controller**

```
{id: "cc8ff2ce-8be9-4de3-a5ba-780c6e81a83d",…}
    id: "cc8ff2ce-8be9-4de3-a5ba-780c6e81a83d"
    description: "Test"
    issuingDate: "2022-05-31T00:00:00"
    fileInfo: {id: "c295007c-c548-48bb-8b6b-7119087426cf", filename: "test.pdf", filetype: "",…}
        contenttype: "application/pdf"
        filename: "artikeldialog.pdf"
        filesize: 1863388
        filetype: ""
        id: "c295007c-c548-48bb-8b6b-7119087426cf"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself, but I'll keep my question and the answer up in case somebody else is looking for the same thing.

All I needed to do is to add

```
builder.ComplexType<DS2.Shared.Models.FileInfo>();
```

in GetEdmModel()